# Structural directives and lazy loaded modules inheritance

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

I'm building a few structural directives to be used within certain modules.
Currently I have nested lazy loaded modules which depend on certain routes from their parent modules.

In short I have a parent module named `company` which uses the root url `:company` which in turn loads lazy loads a module `projects` which uses the url `:company/projects/`.

My question is: I have a structural directive which depends on a service provided in the `company` module. However I wish to also use this directive in my `projects` module. How should I approach this? Currently I get the console error:

```
Can't bind to 'ifCompanyPermission' since it isn't a known property
```

How should I make directives work across modules? I have tested and the directives work fine in each respective module.

Example of how my modules are loaded (these routes belong to the `company` module):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':company',
    component: CompanyComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: IndexComponent,
        canActivate: [PermissionGuard],
      },
      {
        path: 'projects',
        loadChildren: '../projects/projects.module#ProjectsModule',
      },
    }
  }
];
```

**Quickfix:**
Just move the directive to my `shared` module. However, I wish to know if it is possible to share to child modules.

**UPDATE:**
I've noticed a problem when having structural directives in a `shared` module. Whenever I require services from `company` or `projects` module, it will create its own instance of the service. Thus not using the same instance of the service as the `company` or `projects` module itself. Related to [this page](https://angular.io/guide/providers#limiting-provider-scope-by-lazy-loading-modules) in the Angular docs.